# Creating Pivot table and chart with multiple worksheets

Tags: pivot, excel-2007, ms-query

I'm facing a problem regarding creating Pivot table and chart with multiple worksheets.

I have already created a pivot table and chart using Microsoft Query. I followed the steps from this blog: 
http://www.ashishmathur.com/create-a-pivot-table-from-multiple-worksheets-in-the-same-workbook/

Right now, I'm figuring out how I can add new data into pivot table.

Is it possible to add new worksheets of data into already created query and pivot table?

Or do I need to create all over again everytime I add new worksheet of data?

FYI: I'm using Excel 2007 and all my data contains same no. of columns and same column names.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to add just one more block of `UNIONALL Select * from dummy2`.
If you'd need to do it say weekly or daily I recommend getting to know basic macro editing that will enable you to pull data from numerous sheets to a summary one and base your SQL on that single sheet.

```
Sub loop_through_sheets()
Dim ws As Worksheet 'define a worksheet
For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets 'for each worksheet
If ws.Name Like "YourString" Then 'make sure you don't consolidate the summary sheet
Call DataGrab(ws)
End If
Next ws
End Sub
```